# How to send websocket message while waiting to receive?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost-asio, boost-beast, boost-beast-websocket

My goal is to register to a websocket service to get real-time company quotations.

So I based my code on the following example, by mostly calling (again) `async_read`, once we receive a quotation to accept futures quotation:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/async-ssl/websocket_client_async_ssl.cpp

The problem is when I am waiting for a new quotation (who could take sometimes minutes or hours for small companies), the program is blocked waiting for a message and I do not have the opportunity to ask for another company.

I tried to use the "post" function to call again `async_write` in the good context thread but the program crashed.

Is there any way to force the completion of callback `on_read`, to have then the opportunity to send a new message?

Here is the function I modified (simplified without mutexes):

```
void
    on_read(
        beast::error_code ec,
        std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        if(ec)
            return fail2(ec, "read");

        
        std::string mycontent = beast::buffers_to_string(buffer_.data());
        cout << mycontent << endl;
        buffer_.clear();
        
        ws_.async_read(
            buffer_,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_read,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void subscribe(const std::string &symbol)
    {
        // We save the message in the queue
        std::string text = "{\"action\": \"subscribe\", \"symbols\": \"" + symbol + "\"}";
        msgqueue_.push_back(text);
        boost::asio::post(ioc_, beast::bind_front_handler(&session::_subscription_to_post, shared_from_this()));
    }

    void _subscription_to_post()
    {
        if (msgqueue_.empty())
            return;

        // We send the message
        ws_.async_write(
            net::buffer(msgqueue_.front()),
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_write,
                shared_from_this()));
        msgqueue_.pop_front();
    }
```

And the program crashes immediately when trying to `async_write`.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is when I am waiting for a new quotation [...] the program is blocked waiting for a message

It isn't technically blocked because you are using `async_read`

> I tried to use the "post" function to call again async_write in the good context thread, but the program crashed.

That means you're doing something wrong. You can post a question with your self-contained minimal code, and we can tell you what is wrong.

In general, you can use a *single* read operation and a *single* write operation concurrently (as in: in flight, asynchronously, you still need to synchronize threads accessing all related resources).

Typically, you have a single async-read-chain active at all times, and a outbound message-queue that is drained by a single async-write chain (that obviously ends when the queue is empty, so needs to be initiated when the first outbound message is queued).

I have many answers on this site (literally dozens) that you may be able to find by search for `outbox` or `outbox_` e.g. Keep in mind that the majority of them will deal with plain (ssl) sockets intead of websockets, but the pattern practically the same.

> Is there any way to force the completion of callback on_read, to have then the opportunity to send a new message ?

You can technically `cancel()` it, which completes it with `operation_aborted`. But that is not what you need. You want [full-duplex](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full-duplex), so writing `cancel()` is the opposite of what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added a little piece of code of the functions I modified

Comment: In my example, the context is started in a thread, and the "subscribe" fonction" is called from another thread (I have removed mutexes to simplify the reading)

Comment: Please don't remove crucial things like thread synchronization. It's highly likely that it contributes to your issue. In fact, make the code self-contained. There's really no reason to make people guess/write your code again just to answer.

Comment: As proposed, I completely isolated this weekend the code of my websocket management from my large project, and to my surprise it worked as you expected. I dug my full program, and discovered that I had memory corruption somewhere else, with no obvious other effect than crashing my websocket part when trying to write a new message. So thanks to have requested a fully running example, it made me point the problem.

Comment: @moochy Good work! I hope you celebrated the moment. I know the feeling, and yes, this is why I do self-contained tests all the time while prototyping and/or debugging